# Parse string to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsing

Is there by any chance a built-in javascript function that parses:

```
var string = '[2,1,-4]';
var multiString = '[[-3,2,-1][2,-3,2][1,-1,3]]';
```

to

```
var array = [2,1,-4];
var multiArray = [[-3,2,-1],[2,-3,2],[1,-1,3]];
```

or do I have to write a custom function for this?

Comment: You have a syntax error in your resulting multiarray.

Comment: How did you end up with strings and not Arrays?

Comment: That could *almost* be valid JSON, but is not...

Comment: @putvande read from file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your correct your multiString to the correct format
(ie. `'[[-3,2,-1]`**`,`**`[2,-3,2]`**`,`**`[1,-1,3]]'`)

Then yes.

```
array = JSON.parse(string);
multiArray = JSON.parse(multiString);
```

Comment: So if I can change a bit the initial string format is possible.. hmm Thanks!

Comment: He can do `JSON.parse(multiString.replace(/\]\[/g,"],["));` if necessary

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this on your own, it can be done using [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) and [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split). A possible solution could look like this:

```
var multiString = '[[-3,2,-1][2,-3,2][1,-1,3]]';
var string = '[2,1,-4]';    
function parse(input) {
    var s = input;
    // remove leading [ and trailing ] if present
    if (input[0] == "[") {
        s = input.substring(0, input.length);
    }
    if (input[input.length] == "]") {
        s = s.substring(input.length-1, 1);
    }
    // create an arrray, splitting on every ,
    var items = s.split(",");
    return items;
}
// items is now an array holding 2,-1,4
var items = parse(string);
```

You can then split the bigger string into smaller chunks and apply the function to each part using [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
function parseAOfA(input) {
    var s = input.substring(0, input.length).substring(input.length-1, 1);
    s = s.substring(0, s.length).substring(s.length-1, 1);
    s = s.split("][");
    var items = s.map(parse);
    return items;
}
var items = parseAOfA(multiString);
```

Comment: This doesn't work for the multiString '[[-3,2,-1],[2,-3,2],[1,-1,3]]'

Comment: I am extending my answer right now to address this part of the question too.

Comment: Yes, that's the "hard" way to go. I was going to come to this if something like JSON.parse() wouldn't work. Thanks for your time - downvote neutralised.

Comment: @putvande i have updated my code, so my solution now works for both inputs.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, you can use *eval*:

```
var s = '[1,2,3]';
var a = eval(s);
```

however if the string is valid JSON, then as *Niet* suggested, JSON.parse is a much better solution.