# javascript Extract multiple series array from string

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I have string like

```
var t = 'red: 5, purple: 7, fuchsia: 10, green: 8';
```

I want to make array like

```
a = ['red', 'purple', 'fuchsia', 'green'];
b = [ 5, 7, 10, 8]
```

Please help me

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23408574/parse-string-to-array) may be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample solution:

```
const t = 'red: 5, purple: 7, fuchsia: 10, green: 8';

const tarr = t.split(', ');

const a = [];
const b = [];

for (const item of tarr) {
  const [k, v] = item.split(': ');
  a.push(k);
  b.push(~~v); // '~~' is a shortcut to convert string value to number
}

console.log(a, b);
```